# How do you handle session data with ActionCable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, websocket

I'm building an app using Vue and Rails.

I have both the frontend and the backend separate (in separate folders)

The frontend is generated with vue-cli.

I have a situation where, I want to send some data to the backend via websockets, I want to set that data in something like a session object, and then access that data again on subsequent websocket interactions. Is that possible?

Would I need to set some kind of token in the browser, some kind of identifying token?

This seems like it would be a common problem but I can't find any information on it.

Comment: Seems like [this article](https://greg.molnar.io/blog/actioncable-devise-authentication/) may be on point.

Comment: The article says: "The websocket server doesn't have a session" so I guess there's just no session object available, but I have access to user cookies it seems.

Answer (score 0):

If you are utilizing session in rails websocket/connection.rb you won't be able to access it directly, but you can access it through the cookies object. The rails docs say this is labeled ['_session'] but for me on my browser it was ['_session_id'] then whatever data you set within session like a user id ['user_id']

```
cookies.encrypted['_session_id']['YOUR_DATA']
```